# Magnetic opposition for a launch boost

Tags: magnetic-field

Just wondering since we are able to make an object seemingly float or neutrally gravity bouant, is it possible to create a launch pad where electromagnetism is used to "levitate" a vehicle (using repulsive magnetism) to at least decrease the force/energy required to overcome the enertia of liftoff? Thereby significantly decreasing the payload of fuel required to break free of the earths orbit?

Comment: Just wanted to add this in case it helps your question "Magnetic Wormhole Created in Lab" - https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/magnetic-wormhole-created-in-lab/ - "This device can transmit the magnetic field from one point in space to another point, through a path that is magnetically invisible," said study co-author Jordi Prat-Camps, a doctoral candidate in physics at the Autonomous University of Barcelona in Spain. "From a magnetic point of view, this device acts like a wormhole, as if the magnetic field was transferred through an extra special dimension."

Answer (score 1):

A Magnetic Rail Gun assisted launch or vertical mono rail. Most of rockets would have a Mono-pole positive or negative shell or links if done with solid magnets. Electromagnets are sure to interfere with guidance systems Though not impossible just expensive. Most rockets are build by the lowest bidder.